# shebang python line on ubuntu is not working for my webpage

Tags: python, html, shebang

I am writing index.py for my web page test on my Ubuntu laptop.

I wrote `#!usr/bin/env python3` at the top of the code and used some `print()` lines below it.

when I open the webpage under my IP address... the page is not printing what I intended and shows the whole code directly.

Could you see what I was wrong with?

Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't understand python and they shouldn't run any file on your PC, so they will show the file as if it were HTML.
To make a website with python, you can either use a webframework like django  or just write the ouput of your python script into a html/text file.